# What does "definite" mean for a bilinear form over a finite field?

Tags: definition, finite-fields, bilinear-form

What does it mean for a symmetric bilinear form over a finite field to be definite?  Most sources (e.g. Wikipedia) only define definiteness for a form over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  Yet I have seen references to definiteness over finite fields, but I can't find a proper definition.

Comment: I've only seen "definiteness" in the context of "positive-definiteness" or "negative-definiteness", implying some kind of ordering (which finite fields do not have). Do you have some kind of other definiteness in mind over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Can you point us to one of those references to definiteness over finite fields?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found an answer in Lang's *Algebra* (Revised Third Ed., pg. 593):  A symmetric form $b$ is definite if there is no $x\neq 0$ such that $b(x,x)=0$.

Comment: This doesn't agree with the standard definition when the field is ordered, though (because you could have both positive and negative values for $b(x,x)$, but still no zero values, over $\mathbb{Q}$ for example). The usual term for the concept you've described above ( $b(x,x) = 0$ implies $x=0$) is *anisotropic*.